# how to copy the timestamp information of one directory to another in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

in BASH shell, how to copy the timestamp information of one directory to another?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What operating system and filesystem?

Comment: @nmichaels: let's say the standard Mac OS with my macbook pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

touch -r source-dir target-dir

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /path/to/dir1 &&
find . -exec touch --reference={} /path/to/dir2/{} \;
```

This will copy the timestamp information from all the files, directories, etc. in `/path/to/dir1` to `/path/to/dir2`, provided they have the same names.